# How to convert NSURL to String in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurl

How do you convert an NSURL to a String in Swift?

The following:

```
var directoryURL: NSURL
var urlString: String = nsurlObject as String
```

Throws the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to type 'String' in coercion

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It turns out there are properties of NSURL you can access (see [Swift Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW21)):

```
var directoryURL: NSURL
var urlString: String = directoryURL.absoluteString
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.relativeString
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.relativePath
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.path
// etc.
```

Comment: You've missed the one you will probably need most directoryURL.path!